# How to remove bus width from particular column in a file in shell script

Tags: scripts

I have a file like below:

```
               a2bcd, jias, kjsc[4:0], jhsdc;

               ljnd[7], qhqj5qk, ljwndf, qkhe;

               qkjnfqq, jwnwkls, wkjdf[3], wkjen;
```

I need to get below output:

```
                a2bcd, jias, kjsc, jhsdc;

                ljnd, qhqj5qk, ljwndf, qkhe;

                qkjnfqq, jwnwkls, wkjdf, wkjen;
```

That means I need to remove [*] from 1st and 2nd column. Is there any way to do that in shell? If I try removing numbers from entire file it will remove numbers in between text. That should be retained. Only bus width needs to be removed.
TIA

Comment: From your example,, all [*] are removed but you talk of only 1st and énd column.  What do you mean by 'column' then?  What did you try so far? Did you have a look at `sed`, eg?

Comment: I edited the question. Hope now it is clear. sed I tried. But it will remove all digits. My interest is only bus width

Answer (score 0):

You can use any stream editor, i.e. [sed](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html):

```
#/bin/bash
for filename in a2bcd, jias, kjsc[4:0], jhsdc ljnd[7], qhqj5qk, ljwndf, qkhe qkjnfqq, jwnwkls, wkjdf[3], wkjen
do
  echo $filename | sed -E -e 's/(.*)(\[.*\])(.*)/\1\3/'
done
```